# Is it required to prove that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

I attempted the question by showing that the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ to be zero by showing that covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is $0$ (As $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$).But I am confused how to show that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent (although already given in question that $Y=X^2$).

Comment: Contradict the definition of independence. Independence tells you that $P(X \in A , Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B) $ for every pair of sets $A$ and $B$. Show that for this $X$ and $Y$ you can find sets $A,B$ so that this is not true. Alternately, note that independence is equivalent to $E[f(X)g(Y)] = E[f(X)]E[g(Y)]$ for all continuous bounded $f,g$. Can you think of $f,g$ for which this is not true?

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: Even though $Y=X^2$ shows the dependence of $Y$ on $X$, that is the dependence as functions. The dependence as random variables must come from the definition, and cannot be inferred merely from the statement.

Comment: i was thinking if I could find the joint PMF and then show that joint PMF is not equal to product of individual marginal PMF

Comment: That can also be done. I thought a proof by definition would be easier, though. For example : $P(X \in [0,0.5] , Y \in [0.5,1]) = 0$ because if $X \in [0,0.5]$ then $X^2$ cannot be larger than $0.5$. But each of $P(X \in [0,0.5])$ and $P(Y \in [0.5,1])$ has non-zero probability, so we are done.

Comment: actually I am finding a bit difficulty in finding marginal PMF as it is not mentioned if the variables are discrete or continous.could you please tell how to approach

Comment: You have only been asked to show that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. For that, the explanation I give suffices. The marginal PMFs can be calculated , but it is tedious.

Comment: i am a new user so could you please also tell if the image of my question is visible or not

Comment: The link works, so I can see your question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.Keeping in mind those tips I will try to prove it.

Comment: Thank you for adhering to the tips.